# How to add custom title tags to Joomla articles without publishing them as menu items?

Tags: seo, title, joomla3.0

Is there a way to add custom title tags to Joomla articles without having to first publish them as menu items? So far I haven't seen a way to do it, so any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use the Article title or menu title you can only overwrite it by using a dedicated extension.
A few years ago I developed a plugin that does that exactly (SmartSeo) but it's not published any more, so you can try using Sh404Sef (a very comprehensive SEO extension) or other one of that kind.